# PDF/A-3 associated files + Additional XMP RDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mpdf\MpdfException' with message 'Cannot access associated file 'file_path'
```

created PDF/A3 associated File using [this](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/pdf-a3-xmp-rdf.html)

but its not working

my code

```
$constructor = [
        'mode' => 'utf-8',
        'PDFA' => true,
        'PDFAauto' => true,
    ];
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($constructor);

    $mpdf->SetAssociatedFiles([[
        'name' => 'general-customer-invoice.xml',
        'mime' => 'text/xml',
        'description' => 'some description',
        'AFRelationship' => 'Alternative',
        'path' => __DIR__ . '/xml/test.xml'
    ]]);
    //echo __DIR__ . '/xml/test.xml';die();


    $rdf  = '<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:zf="urn:ferd:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#">'."\n";
    $rdf .= '  <zf:DocumentType>INVOICE</zf:DocumentType>'."\n";
    $rdf .= '  <zf:DocumentFileName>ZUGFeRD-invoice.xml</zf:DocumentFileName>'."\n";
    $rdf .= '  <zf:Version>1.0</zf:Version>'."\n";
    $rdf .= '  <zf:ConformanceLevel>BASIC</zf:ConformanceLevel>'."\n";
    $rdf .= '</rdf:Description>'."\n";

    $mpdf->SetAdditionalXmpRdf($rdf);
```

Comment: Does that XML file exist at that path?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes exist

Comment: You might need to crack the mpdf code open then. Put a `debug_print_backtrace` right before the exception to see what it is complaining about: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/cc1759f153c948c76b0ef54a39a6186be9965def/src/Writer/MetadataWriter.php#L296

Comment: I doubt your code example here matches what you are actually running. Based on the error message you must have `'path' => 'file_path'` in your code. Share an actual code example